# Python- Is it wrong to use default values for required parameters in function def?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a func which looks like this:

```
def somefunc(param1, param2, param3=None, param4=None, param5=None):
    if not all([param3, param4, param5]):
        raise ValueError("Invalid Parameters")

    #continue with rest of the logic if no "ValueError"
```

`param3, param4, param5` are all required by the func. I have a restriction of max 3 positionals based on how the func is called. I can either gather them as individual keyword parameters with default values of `None` like I have shown above OR as `**kwargs` which can accept a dictionary of params.

Since I am checking if each param has some value assigned or else raise a `ValueError`, is it wrong to use such default values for required params during func def.
I understand the problem with mutable default values as explained here [Default Parameter Values in Python](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm). But is using a sentinel object or something like `None` for required func args still a bad practice?

Also if this is not a good practice what would be a right way to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: It's not exactly "wrong", but if they're required, why not just make them required arguments by omitting the defaults? You can still pass them as keyword arguments (`def func(foo, bar)` can be called with `func(bar=2, foo=1)`).

Comment: Yes, it is logically wrong (though syntactically OK).  If the parameters are required, make the user provide them by not specifying a default.  If they're not required, why are you testing that they're all provided.

Comment: Why are you giving them default values if it’s incorrect to call them with their default values?

Comment: I forgot to add a restriction: I can only provide 3 positionals based on how the api actually calls the func.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? Python 3 can have keyword-only variables, using syntax like `def somefunc(param1, param2, *, param3, param4):`. The `*` indicates that the rest of the parameters are keyword-only, and since they have no defaults, they are required.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3, you can have required variables that must be passed by keyword:

```
def somefunc(pos1, pos2, *, kwonly3, kwonly4): # kwonly3 and kwonly4 are still required!
    pass
```

But I'm not sure that you necessarily need this. If your function would make sense with the parameters all being positional, you can still call it via an API that passes them by keyword:

```
def somefunc2(pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4): # all parameters are required
    pass

# you can call the function with keyword arguments, or even with **kwargs
somefunc2("foo", "bar", pos3="baz", **{"pos4": "quux"}) # this will work
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing wrong number of arguments to a function is `TypeError` in Python. Passing a wrong value such as `None` in your case may be `ValueError`.

To emulate `somefunc(param1, param2, *, param3, param4, param5)` in Python 2:

```
def somefunc(param1, param2, **kwargs):
    if somefunc.kwargs != sorted(kwargs):
        raise TypeError('Expected exactly %d keyword-only args: %r; got %r' % (
                        len(somefunc.kwargs), somefunc.kwargs, kwargs))
    if any(v is None for v in kwargs.values()):
        raise ValueError("%s can't be None; got %r" % (
                         ", ".join(somefunc.kwargs), kwargs))
somefunc.kwargs = ['param3', 'param4', 'param5']
```